# How To Split a Hamburger Menu Into Two Columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, menu, nav, dreamweaver, hamburger-menu

I'm a beginner and a boomer.  I'm learning Dreamweaver through the manual and youtube videos and this is literally my third day.  There might be a simple way to do this, but I cannot figure it out and a search for the answer is turning up nothing.  I want to create a website menu with 12 pages.  Obviously, that's too long on a hamburger menu for mobile users.  I'd like to break that menu into two columns of 6 pages each.

I'm using a youtuber's tutorials named Jong-Yoon Kim.  He's an excellent instructor and I've learned a lot from him.  Below is the code that he had us prepare for the menu, but I added additional pages (my future website will have 12 pages).  As you can see in a mobile preview, it is too long and pushes the contents of the page down very far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopt</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
    </nav>
<!-- body code goes here -->


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I marked up a screenshot of what I'd like to do, if it's possible.[Mobile Hamburger Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsT0m.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopt</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>  
</ul>
```

Comment: OMG!  THANK YOU!!!  Sorry, I didn't know anyone replied.  I thought I would receive an email when people posted answers.  Thank you so much for taking the time to do that!  I really appreciate it!!!